# insufficientPermissions Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I already have a google analytics account. so when I try to run HelloAnalytics.php following [Hello Analytics API: PHP quickstart for service accounts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php)

[image]

It's response:

> {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"insufficientPermissions","message":"User does not have any Google Analytics account."}]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to authenticate to Google Analytics using a Service account.  Service accounts by default do not have any google analytics accounts.

> Add service account to Google Analytics account
>   The newly created service account will have an email address, -@developer.gserviceaccount.com; Use this email address to add a user to the Google analytics account you want to access via the API. For this tutorial only Read & Analyze permissions are needed.

Comment: It worked after I add email address, -@developer.gserviceaccount.com to google analytics. Thanks you so much!.